# Issues / bad datas while retrieving result from a triple nested entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

First of all, don't hesitate if you need more details, I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I created a website that allows users to create mangas, by created 3 scaffolds : one for the manga itself, that has many chapters, which belongs to the manga, and has many pages inside of it.

For a better user experience, I replaces the IDs in the URL by chapter numbers and page numbers, and used FriendlyID to have the manga's name inside the URL, so the first page from a manga's first chapter would look like the following: `localhost:3000/epic-manga/1/1`.

Since all the routes are nested, the route itself needs three parameters: the 'manga_id', the 'chapter_number' and the 'page_number'. However, I didn't find useful to set up the manga variable since I though that Rails knew what I was talking about. However, while I was integrating the pages in my layout, I realized that Rails was displaying the wrong results :

```
  private
    #Peji stands for 'page' in japanese, don't ask
    def set_peji
      @chapter = Chapter.find_by(chapter_number: params[:chapter_id])
      @peji = @chapter.pejis.find_by(scan_number: params[:id])
    end
```

The Rails doc says that 'find_by' will select the first item that matches its research. When I load the page, the SQL request looks like this: `SELECT  'chapters'.* FROM 'chapters' WHERE 'chapters'.'chapter_number' = 1 LIMIT 1`. Yet, every single mangas have at least a first chapter.

My biggest problem is that I don't really know how to setup the 'set_peji' function to limit the search to the manga that owns the chapters / pages, so I tried the following:

```
def set_peji
  @manga = Manga.find_by(slug: params[:manga_id])
  @chapter = @manga.chapters.find_by(chapter_number: params[:chapter_id])
  @peji = @manga.chapters.pejis.find_by(scan_number: params[:id])
end
```

However, I have this error as a result: `undefined method 'pejis' for #<Chapter::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fbe30667380>` while targetting the line containing '@peji' (I tried replacing '@manga.chapters.pejis' by '@chapter.pejis' but it gets me a wrong result)

I don't really have any other idea, I'm open to any suggestion.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually really close. You've just gotten your nesting wrong on the `peji` line. Your nested queries will work if they look like this:

```
def set_peji
  @manga = Manga.find_by(slug: params[:manga_id])
  @chapter = @manga.chapters.find_by(chapter_number: params[:chapter_id])
  @peji = @chapter.pejis.find_by(scan_number: params[:id])
end
```

The reason you're getting an error on `@manga.chapters.pejis` is that `@manga.chapters` is a "`Collection`" (you can think of it as an `Array`) and that object doesn't know how to respond to `pejis`, whereas `@chapter` is only a single `Chapter` object, and it is aware of the `pejis` relationship to a `chapter`.

This of course assumes you've got the following relationship setup in your models (which is how I tested the above code):

```
# app/models/manga.rb
class Manga < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chapters
end

# app/models/chapter.rb
class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manga
  has_many :pejis
end

# app/models/peji.rb
class Peji < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chapter
end
```

Comment: You were right, I was so close it drives me insane ! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Jaeger welcome to programming, and/or rails. 10 years in and I've started to make fewer of those mistakes ;)

Comment: 2 years and a half and I'm rather happy to get this close to a functional code :D